# How can I replicate this grid using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

So I was trying to replicate this grid with `grid-auto-flow: column;` but I wasn't able to achieve it.

Issue #1: Container should be horizontal scrollable since it can have many more options
Issue #2: Since I was using grid each column has taking the longest item and instead of grouping all the elements on the image they were separated
note: should only contain two rows

So far I was only able to achieve this example:

[image]

but since each column is taking a specific width it is leaving some space between 1 & 3 and 3 & 5

this is the code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(auto, 1fr));
  gap: 8px;
}
.module {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div style="width: 96px;" class="module">1</div>
  <div style="width: 128px;" class="module">2</div>
  <div style="width: 176px;" class="module">3</div>
  <div style="width: 208px;" class="module">4</div>
  <div style="width: 176px;" class="module">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you see it as a zig-zag? for me it's a simple layout where you have 2 rows because the first one cannot fit all the elements

Comment: Your first image IS NOT A GRID

Comment: Oh then how can i replicate if it is not a grid?

Comment: it COULD be a grid but it really is a flex row ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox

Comment: Using flex would get the right layout, but not the right order based on the image. This is basically a sideways masonry layout. Obviously this only applies if they need that order.

Answer (score 1):

Just change to flex and remove some things in the CSS. I will leave the content style out of this since it is not about that here.

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 8px;
}
.module {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div style="width: 96px;" class="module">1</div>
  <div style="width: 128px;" class="module">2</div>
  <div style="width: 176px;" class="module">3 i AM BIGGER</div>
  <div style="width: 208px;" class="module">4</div>
  <div style="width: 176px;" class="module">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the same solution as the pre-existing answer.

Comment: @Sean similar but with the `flex-flow: row wrap;` different there

Comment: That's just shorthand for the same thing.

Comment: Yep, different ways to paint a barn; brush, roller, sprayer, toss a bucket etc.

Comment: It's not different though; just an alternate syntax. The same properties are being set. It's not different enough to constitute a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this answer may be a little controversial, but I welcome any feedback/issues.

This fixes the issues of:

1. Only two rows
2. Scrolling horizontally
3. Being in a brick layout

This does NOT solve the issue of the item ordering, which may or may not be a deal breaker.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.grid {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.grid div {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  writing-mode: initial;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div>1. lorem</div>
    <div>2. ipsum</div>
    <div>3. dolor sit</div>
    <div>4. sit ips</div>
    <div>5. amet</div>
    <div>6. lorem</div>
    <div>7. ipsum</div>
    <div>8. dolor sit</div>
    <div>9. sit ips</div>
    <div>10. amet</div>
    <div>11. lorem</div>
    <div>12. ipsum</div>
    <div>13. dolor sit</div>
    <div>14. sit ips</div>
    <div>15. amet</div>
    <div>16. lorem</div>
    <div>17. ipsum</div>
    <div>18. dolor sit</div>
    <div>19. sit ips</div>
    <div>20. amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So this is cool since it solves two issues but in this case i need to order the items by column, because the first two elements are always there but 3, 4, 5 is depends on the user data, so instead of having a long row i want it to fill it in that way

Comment: In this case it's really just a masonry layout and would need js to position them. I'd question the designs you've been given/done and get them updated to work in a more natural way for a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider letting the items wrap naturally within a [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) container (shown in red in the example below).

```css
.details {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 500px;
  background: red;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.detail {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.detail dd {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<dl class="details">
  <div class="detail">
    <dt><img alt="Reviews" src="https://placekitten.com/36/36" width="36" height="36"/></dt>
    <dd><strong>5 star average</strong> from over 34 reviews</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <dt><img alt="Order Requirements" src="https://placekitten.com/36/36" width="36" height="36"/></dt>
    <dd><strong>$6.00</strong> minimum order</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <dt><img alt="Location" src="https://placekitten.com/36/36" width="36" height="36"/></dt>
    <dd><strong>Richmond</strong> county</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <dt><img alt="Prep Time" src="https://placekitten.com/36/36" width="36" height="36"/></dt>
    <dd><strong>20 min</strong> preparation</dd>
  </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <dt><img alt="Flexibility" src="https://placekitten.com/36/36" width="36" height="36"/></dt>
    <dd><strong>Orders up to 1 day</strong> in advance</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```